# Vlookup for multiple Ranges

Tags: excel, vba

The below code is for VLOOKUP result in same cell, which is working well, but now I also need VLOOKUP values for Range("K:L"), (R:S) and further.

My vlookup formula is this :

> nx = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(batch, Sheets("Batch Card REGISTER").Range("D:E"), 2, False)

> Column Index no : 2

Result I need: If i type the Qty in Cl no 10, it will verify the value from the other sheet based on the 'batch'. The column index no for all the ranges is same i.e. 2

Example: If i type 100 in Cl no 10, it will verify in the "Batch Card Register" whether the value of the mentioned batch is 100 or not. If value is not 100 i have added a code so it will return the original value which is 90.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim check
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim mx As Double
    Dim nx As Double
    Dim batch
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Rg As Range
    
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "FGIM@22"

    For Each cl In Target.Cells
        
        If Target.Column = 10 And Target.Offset(0, -3).Value = "Product_In" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
          
            batch = Target.Offset(0, -6)
            Set Rg = Sheets("Batch Card REGISTER").Range("D:E")
            nx = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(batch, Sheets("Batch Card REGISTER").Range("D:E"), 2, False)
           
            If Target.Value And nx <> Target.Value Then
                MsgBox "NOTE: Value does not Match" & VBA.Constants.vbNewLine & "Orginal Value from Batch Card Register will be Restored", vbOKOnly, "ENTRY ERROR!"
                Target.Value = nx
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    
       Verify entry in column J when "Dispatch" in is column G
        If Target.Column = 10 And Target.Offset(0, -3).Value = "Dispatch" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
         
            batch = Target.Offset(0, -6)
            Set rng = Sheets("FG Register").Columns("D:I")
            mx = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Target.Offset(0, -6), Sheets("FG Register").Columns("D:I"), 6, False)
           
            If Target.Value And mx < 0 Then
                MsgBox "Value in Current Stock cannot exceed " & mx, vbOKOnly, "ENTRY ERROR!"
                Target.Value = Target.Value + mx
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
        
        If Target.Column = 10 Then
            check = MsgBox("NOTE: CANNOT be edited after confirmation, Confirm the Entry?", vbYesNo, "Confirm Entry")
            If check = vbYes Then
                Range("A" & cl.Row & ":J" & cl.Row).Locked = True
            Else
                Range("C" & cl.Row & ":H" & cl.Row).Locked = False
            End If
        End If
    
    Next cl
          
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1:AA1000")) Is Nothing Then
        ThisWorkbook.Save
    End If    
End Sub
```

Comment: Depending on the quantity, you need to check in some range or another? your code depends on the value in cell J I think.

Comment: Why use `VLookup()` for this?  If you want `Worksheetfunction`, then `Index`/`Match` may make your life easier... and better yet, you can use `Find`/`FindNext` which are not `Worksheetfunction` and will function over multiple columns.

Comment: @ Damion.. Cell J is where the Quantity input is going to be. Depending on the batch, i need to check some range and it will look the Qty

Comment: @ Cyril... Can you help me with the Find/FindNext?? Im not really familiar with VBA.